# Compare two text columns to measure their similarity in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, lambda, apply, fuzzywuzzy, sequencematcher

I want to compare columns A with C and also B with C and measure each pair's similarity and then report the one that has a higher degree of similarity.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['JAMES LIKEN', 'LINDEN R. EVANS', 'LINDEN R. EVANS'], ['HENRY THEISEN', 'SCOTT ULLEM', 'Henry J. Theisen']])
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Result should be in the form of three columns. The first two contain similarity ratio and the third column should contain either column A or B, whichever that is more similar  to C. I used `fuzz.partial_ratio` and `sequencematcher`, and used `apply` and `lambda` to use the function for each row, but it led to error.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried and an example of the wanted result, that'd greatly help.

Comment: I tried different codes, but none of them worked. Here are some examples:
df['sim'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['A'], x['C']), axis=1)
df['sim'] = df[['A', 'C']].apply(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(lambda y: y == " ", x[0], x[1]).ratio(), axis=1)